# Strange image behaviour of Navigation Bar Item

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mono, uibarbuttonitem

I am working on an xamarin mvvmcross app. 
I am using a LeftBarButtonItem to open/close a flyoutmenu, this works now.

But for some wierd reason I cannot get the image to load properly.

```
NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem (UIImage.FromBundle("menu-button"),UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain , (s, e) =>{

};
```

This wil show the button as a solid blue rectangle:

[image]

But if i call this  afterwards

```
NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromBundle("menu-button"),UIControlState.Normal,UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

It loads the image but behind the blue rectangle... all stretched out like so:

[image]

I figured this could be fixed if I changed the first line to

```
NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem ("",UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain , (s, e) =>{

};
```

But then it renders the image outside of the Navigation bar... Cannot post a screenshot of that because of low rep.

How can I make it so that the background image loads properly? The size of the image in the first screenshot is correct but I can not figure out why it is solid blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call .ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal) on the UIImage, so it won't be a template.

I have a helper method for this.

```
public static UIImage GetOriginal(this UIImage image) => 
    image.ImageWithRenderingMode (UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
```